# How to select all fields for a given model along with selected fields from association using struct to avoid over-fetching

Tags: elixir, ecto

In this query, is there any way to define all fields of `Candidate` struct in select? (* to be replaced by list of fields):

```
from([candidate: candidate, zone: zone, batch: batch, region: region] in query,
 join: af in assoc(zone, :af),
 join: zc in assoc(zone, :zc),
 join: cc_zone in assoc(candidate, :cc_zone),
 join: training_language in assoc(candidate, :training_language),
 join: state in assoc(candidate, :state),
 left_join: interview in assoc(candidate, :interview),
 preload: [
   zone: zone,
   batch: batch,
   training_language: training_language,
   state: state
 ],
 select: 
  struct(
    candidate,
    [
      *,
      training_language: [:id, :name],
      batch: [:id, :identifier],
      zone: [:id, :code],
      state: [:id, :code]
    ]
  )
)
```

or do we need to add all the fields in the candidates table manually?

--

one of the suggestions received in slack, which did not work as intended:

```
select: canditate
select_merge: struct(
    candidate,
    [
      training_language: [:id, :name],
      batch: [:id, :identifier],
      zone: [:id, :code],
      state: [:id, :code]
    ]
)
```

This returns candidate struct with all fields from all preloaded associations

Comment: is there any reason you are using queries instead of Repo.preload?

Comment: @Daniel For avoiding over-fetching. only one of two fields from the associations are being used whereas associations have loads of fields.

Answer (score 0):

`select: candidate` should select all fields of candidate. Also, since you preloaded all the necessary assocs, they will also be selected automatically.

Comment: as mentioned in the question, ```select: candidate``` with preload fetches all the data from all the associations. The whole point of the above question is to avoid over-fetching which is defeated in this case.